# trying to get data from hubspot

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, hubspot, proxy-server

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am trying to fetch data from hubspot by using API key. So I am getting errors like cors policies issues. To overcome that issue I have created node proxy server to get data from hubspot.
By using below codes, I am getting data in different localhost like after calling get requests from reactjs, getting data from hotspot in localhost:3000/api but its supposed to come in the localhost3000 within the table format.

```
App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Row, Col, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

function ContactComponent() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const pageSize = 10; // Number of contacts per page
  const apiKey = 'I have used my api key';

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchContacts() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts`
          , {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`
            }
          }
          //`https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?hapikey=${apiKey}&count=${pageSize}&vidOffset=${(currentPage - 1) * pageSize}`
        );

        const newContacts = response.data.contacts;
        setContacts(newContacts);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching contacts:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchContacts();
  }, [currentPage]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>HubSpot Contacts</h1>
      <Row>
        {contacts.map(contact => (
          <Col key={contact.vid} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
            <Card className="mb-3">
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{contact.properties.firstname.value} {contact.properties.lastname.value}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>Email: {contact.properties.email.value}</Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
      <div className="text-center">
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={() => setCurrentPage(prevPage => prevPage - 1)}
          disabled={currentPage === 1}
        >
          Previous Page
        </button>
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary ml-2"
          onClick={() => setCurrentPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1)}
        >
          Next Page
        </button>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default ContactComponent;
```

```
Proxy server
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const port = 3000; // Choose a port for the proxy server

const hubspotApiKey = ''; // Replace with your HubSpot API key

app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization');
  next();
})
app.get('/hubspot-contacts', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hubspotResponse = await axios.get('https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${hubspotApiKey}`
      },
      params: {
        count: 10,
        vidOffset: req.query.vidOffset || 0
      }
    });

    res.json(hubspotResponse.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching HubSpot contacts:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First API keys were deprecated back in November - HubSpot did make some exceptions (to my knowledge), but in general, API keys should no longer work for most accounts. You should use private apps instead.

Not sure if I understood your question correctly - but HubSpot, for security issues, doesn't support Ajax API requests (this will make the API key/public app token available to the public, which is a big security hole). What you're doing is correct - you are using server side scripting (Server A) for API requests, and then getting the data from your server (Server A) using Ajax.